# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 170: invalid start byte

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to do this:

```
fh = request.FILES['csv']
fh = io.StringIO(fh.read().decode())
reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=";")
```

This is failing always with the error in title and I spent almost 8 hours on this.

here is my understanding:

I am using python3, so file `fh` is in bytes. I am encoding it into string and putting it in memory via StringIO.

with `csv.DictReader()` trying to read it as dict into memory. It is failing here:

[image]

also tried with `io.StringIO(fh.read().decode('utf-8'))`, but same error.

what am I missing? :/

Answer (score 0):

The error is because there is some non-ASCII character in the file and it can't be encoded/decoded. One simple way to avoid this error is to encode/decode such strings with encode()/decode() function as follows (if a is the string with non-ASCII character):

`a.decode('utf-8')`

Also, you could try opening the file as:

`with open('filename', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    your code using f as file pointer`

use 'rb' if your file is binary.